# Precipitation or snow cover raster data for Scandinavia

Tags: raster, modis, climate

I am looking for free precipitation or snow cover data in Scandinavia mountain during the winter 2011-2012. The WorldClim dataset is not enough acute. I would like 500 m scale at least. There is NASA's MODIS, but MOD10 (MOD10A2 for instance) are not available. Does anybody know where I can find these kind of data? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this link http://nsidc.org/data/modis/data_versions.html#temporal . It says MOD10A2 V5 has temporal coverage from 2002 to present.

MODIS/Terra **MOD10A2**

Version 3 (V003) : 2000-10-31 to 2002-12-31
Version 4 (V004) : 2000-02-24 to 2007-01-03
Version 5 (V005) : 2000-02-24 to present